# How can I dont show the preference dialog after user select the listpreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-dialog

After the user selects the list of ListPreference in the PreferenceFragmant. 
Now user need to touch any space outside the dialog to go back to mainActivity. 
How can I immediately go back to the Activity, instead of showing the dialog box again?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListPreference listPreference = new ListPreference(this); 
Dialog dialog = listPreference.getDialog();

if (dialog != null) {
    dialog.hide();
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve line:
Dialog dialog = listPreference.getDialog();